# PHP file not found on local apache server

Tags: php, apache, authentication

I am setting up a PHP login using Apache on my computer. I created a login form named `login.php` and I can access it.I also created a file named `auth.php` and when the login forum sends me to it (with some arguments at the end) my apache server says **404 not found** and does not login.But `curl 127.0.0.1/auth.php` works and and gives a blank output while `curl 127.0.0.1/auth.php&lwv=110` doesn't.

Running Apache 2.4.7 on elementary OS (based on Ubuntu)

Comment: @thewbmstr Works. Add it as an answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `127.0.0.1/auth.php&lwv=110` change to `127.0.0.1/auth.php?lwv=110`

Or `localhost/auth.php?lwv=110`